# subdomain show just blank space

Tags: centos, subdomain, plesk, cloudflare

I have a dedicated server centos 6.4 with plesk 12. I created to my existing domain.com an subdomain media.mydomain.com to move store there the images.

I created the subdomain also on provider side (3days ago). I also create an A Record on cloud flare point to my static servers ip (2 days ago). When I enter yet, media.mydomain.com to the browser, I get just a blank page, nothing more. When I check the DNS for my subdomain then i get the following message:

> Delegation not found at parent.
>
> No delegation could be found at the parent, making your zone unreachable from the Internet.
>
> Not enough name server information was found to test the zone media.mydomain.com, but an IP address lookup succeeded in spite of that.

I don't know, how i can get my subdomain working, can someone give me tip, how i can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

A blank page in your browser actually sounds like a server issue not delivering content. Difficult to look at without knowing the actual subdomain in question.

Comment: the subdomain is media.detoxplanner.com

Comment: I think I already responded to a support ticket about this issue. The problem is on your server, unfortunately, so you need to contact your hosting provider (curls are not returning any content).